# How can I get full link to an image in the img tag through the Html helper (image method)?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have this code snippet in an email layout:

```
  <div>
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('Layouts/default/Logo.png', array(
      'alt' => 'Setin SRL',
      'url' => $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'index'), true)
    )); ?>
  </div>
```

However this is not ok. I can get the FULL url to the website through `url(array('action' => 'index'), true)`

But I can't find any paramater that I can set to true for image too. Any suggestion or workaround on how can I do this?

**Edit 1:**
Basically, I need this link: `Layouts/default/Logo.png` to become `http://www.something.com/Layouts/default/Logo.png` in the *img src*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always use

```
$this->Html->link($this->Html->image(...), $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'index'), true), array('escape'=>false));
```

Comment: Wait, my problem is the reference to the image, not the link! See my edit

Comment: thats my point. you just don't use image with url combined this way (I never liked it that you can add an url this way in the first place). PS: you can do the same inside the image() tag: `$this->Html->image($this->Html->url(..., true))`

Comment: Yea but if I use the *url* method I miss the possibility to get automatically "linked" to the img directory (http://mywebsite.something/img/Layouts/default/Logo.png), I have to add it manually. I know is stupid but I'm not using the pretty urls feature (host problems) so I get a http://mywebsite.something/index.php/img/... which is not ok obviusly

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because I discovered there isn't another way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<?
echo $this->Html->image(Router::url('/') . 'Layouts/default/Logo.png');
?>
```

Comment: While I think your answer is **logically** the correct one, I think cake has a sort of bug, infact it outputs: /app/webroot/index.php/Layouts/default/Logo.png
the "index.php" obviusly is creating the problem (remember that I have the rewrite mod disabled for hosting problems)

Comment: Oh interesting, can you try Router::url('/', true) ? Does that work?

Comment: With "true" I get a different result but still not good: `http://www.xxx.com.localhost:8080/index.php/Layouts/default/Logo.png"`

Comment: I see. Didn't realize that turning off mod_rewrite has this effect. Can you do str_replace("index.php", "", Router::url('/', true)) - that should work.

Comment: Yea obvius but I hoped for an already working things. I already solved as you suggested :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably the [HtmlHelper::assetUrl](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-Helper.html#_assetUrl) function that is used in the implementation of `image` method:

```
public function image($path, $options = array()) {
    $path = $this->assetUrl($path, $options + array('pathPrefix' => Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl')));
    ...
```

Comment: I believe this wasn't available when I worked on this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = '<img src="http://some-img-link" alt="some-img-alt"/>';

$src = preg_match('/<img src=\"(.*?)\">/', $img);

echo $src;
```

I want to get the `src` value from the img tag and maybe the alt value