# Image link in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want to make an image link, for that I wrote the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
           $this->Html->image('logo.png', array('height' => '100', 'width' => '100','escape' => false)),
    array('controller'=>'officers','action'=>'home'));
?>
```

it doesn't show the image, instead of image it shows the following line in link:

```
 <img src="/event_management/img/logo.png" height="100" width="100" alt="" />
```

the link is working. How can I show the image?

Comment: @duplicate question found: [How can I get a full link to an image in the img tag through the Html helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057491/how-can-i-get-full-link-to-an-image-in-the-img-tag-through-the-html-helper-imag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing `escape => false` from your image, and add slash before your image as its relative to your `app/webroot` folder , as:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('/<your-img-folder>/logo.png',array('height' => '100', 'width' => '100')),
    array(
        'controller' => 'zones', 
        'action' => 'index'
    ), array('escape' => false)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

A much better option would be using url parameter in Html->image itself

```
$this->Html->image('logo.png', array('height' => '100', 'width' => '100','url' => array(
    'controller' => 'zones', 
    'action' => 'index'
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it:

```
$html->link($html->image('fancy-theme/appstore.png',array('height' => '27', 'width' => '94', 'alt' => 'Download on App Store')), 'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/[string]', array('id' => 'appstoredownload', 'escape' => false));
```