# CakePHP Clickable Image

Tags: image, cakephp, click

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. So far this code is not working for me.

This is the original code. As you can see it is just an image which cannot be clicked:

```
echo $this->Html->image('logo.png', array('alt' => 'Logo', 'id' => 'logo'));
```

Then this is what I'm doing right now. I want the logo to be clickable so that it would redirect me to index.ctp.

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('logo.png'), array(
                                'escape' => false,
                                'controller' => 'websites', 
                                'action' => 'index'
                            ));
```

So on my website this thing appears as a link where the logo should be:

```
<img src="/appname/img/logo.png" alt="" />
```

My logo is stored under the img folder. I didn't change anything so I really don't know what's happening here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image link in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008403/image-link-in-cakephp)

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008403/image-link-in-cakephp. 2nd arg, set the escape option in the array to true. **Or** use the url option in the image method options array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->image("logo.png", 
     array(
            "alt" => "logo",
            'url' => array(
                           'controller' => 'home',
                           'action' => 'index'
             )
     )
 );
```

Output will be :

```
<a href="/home/index">
   <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
</a>
```

For more read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html